# Get Compression Algorithm of Images with Java

Tags: java, image

Anyone knows how to? Any recommended libraries? Specifically, I would like to know whether a TIFF image has a LZW or ZIP compression, or if a JPEG image has an 8-bit Huffman Coding algorithm. Thanks Guys!

Been using org.apache.commons.imaging.ImageInfo#getCompressionAlgorithm to do the job. But it seems it cannot recognize ZIP and Huffman compression algorithms. Tried searching on the net as well for possible solutions, but I can't seem to find any that fits my needs.

Comment: Show your research efforts and what you have attempted to get better help here

Comment: @HithamS.AlQadheeb added in edit

Comment: TIFF files has a `compression` tag, so if you find a tool, like [metadata-extractor](https://code.google.com/p/metadata-extractor/), to parse the TIFF structure you could get it from there.